# Let $f(x) = x^5 + x^3 +2x +1$ and let $g$ be its inverse. Let $a,b \in\mathbb R$ with $a < b$. Show that $g(b) − g(a) \le 0.5(b −a)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, mean-value-theorem

Let $f(x) = x^5 + x^3 +2x +1$ and let $g$ be its inverse.  Let $a,b \in\mathbb R$ with $a < b$.  Show that $g(b) − g(a) \le 0.5(b −a)$

I know that $f(x)$ is both continuous and differentiable, so it's possible to use the mean value theorem on it. The inequality also suggests the use of the mean value theorem on the inverse function, but I don't know how to proceed.

Any help would be kindly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles. (You are invited to [edit] your question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f'(x)=5x^{4}+3x^{2}+2 \geq 2$. This implies $g'(x)=\frac 1 {f'(g(x))}\leq \frac 1  2$. Now apply MVT.